# Java JRE: Setting default heap size

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, java, jre, memory-limit

I'm having trouble with Java on a virtual server, it always gives me the following error:

```
# java
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

I first solved this by using the CACAO virtual machine (of OpenJDK, by putting it first in jvm.cfg), but then I run into problems with my web application (Play! framework based, gives me nasty LinkageErrors). So I cannot use that VM. Instead I'd like to just use the normal server VM and **set `-Xmx128M` by default. How can I do that?**

Related: [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28943/ca-certificates-java-fails-when-trying-to-install-openjdk-6-jre)

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution [given on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6763527/445711) - which is to hard code your -Xmx and -Xms settings into the **deps.py** file in "framework/pym/play/commands/"